# What's the better way to write 2 byte arrays to an OutputStream?

Tags: java, android, performance, outputstream

I have two byte arrays that I need to write to an OutputStream on a Socket. Right now I do something like this:

```
byte[] arr1, arr2;
OutputStream os;
os.write(arr1);
os.write(arr2);
```

I was wondering if it's perhaps better to instead first combine the two arrays (e.g. with `System.arraycopy()`) and only then call `os.write(combinedArray)` once?

And if it matters, I'm asking from an Android perspective.

Comment: Depends on the `OutputStream` implementation.

Comment: Now that I think a bit more about it: that's what a BufferedOutputStream does, transparently (at least if the two arrays are smaller than its buffer size).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think technically, you'd be better off wrapping your **OutputStream** in a **BufferedOutputStream** and write each *byte[]* separately.  When you're done writing, call *bufferedOutputStream.flush();*  The BufferedOutputStream will automatically write when its own internal buffer gets full, no matter how many times you write to it with separate byte arrays, and the call to flush ensures that all of the data gets written.  The underlying BufferedOutputStream will determine when it's most efficient to logically combine the byte arrays for you, so you don't have make your code messy with extra logic.

Comment: I think it depends on the length of the arrays, whether you plan to leave the stream open or closed between writes, and whether there is an additional process waiting at the far end for data to arrive.  If you're just writing to a file, then probably not.  If you're writing to a socket, then maybe.